# PhpStorm - How to show deployment log

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

There used to be a log at the bottom which was showing the status of the deployment. E.g. after I saved a file, it was uploaded to the remote server and I was getting a message like "Automatic upload succeeded" or similar.

The log disappeared, how can I open that window again?

Answer (score 1):

I found it under *View -> Tool Windows -> File Transfer*

I thought that it is not working and it is the false window, because I forgot to set the default deployment server, and thus nothing was uploaded to the remote server.

Comment: I had this issue happen after I added a second remote host. Even if you select the proper host in the Remote Host window it doesn't upload to it. You need to open up the deployment configuration settings and select that host as default.